# Groovy Geb - groovy-xml module conflick

Tags: groovy, geb

I am trying to run a simple Groovy script that utilizes Geb to fetch a title. However, I receive an error:
`Module [groovy-xml is loaded in version 4.0.2 and you are trying to load version 3.0.8`

I user Groovy version 4.02. GROOVY_HOME is set; I installed Groovy via sdkman.

```sh
$ groovy -version
Groovy Version: 4.0.2 JVM: 17.0.3 Vendor: Amazon.com Inc. OS: Linux
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19 LTS
```

```
// @Grab(group='org.gebish', module='geb-core', version='5.1')
@Grapes([
    @Grab("org.gebish:geb-core:5.1"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.141.59"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.141.59")
])

import geb.Browser

Browser.drive {

    go "http://example.com"
    println title
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You can use @GrabExclude(‘org.codehaus.groovy:*’)

Comment: @emilles The error disappeared. Do you know the reason of this conflict; that is why we have to do the exclusion?

Comment: You project includes Groovy 4 and geb-core includes Groovy 3. There is currently no conflict resolution for Grab and the project libraries.